# Nativescript Vue DevTools - vue-devtools stuck "Waiting for connection..."

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, devtools

I cannot manage to get the Vue DevTools running with my iOS Nativescript Project. I followed exactly the instruction on https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/getting-started/vue-devtools/ but the Nativescript App does not connect to `vue-devtools`.

I'm working on a Mac having latest Nativescript 8.1.3 installed, `nativescript-vue-devtools` is version 1.5.1.

One thing I notice is the error message **ReferenceError: SocketManager is not defined** as soon as I put `Vue.use(VueDevtools)` into the code. This error message always appears, I tried several Simulators with different iOS version, I also tried a physical device. I also tried with a "fresh" blank Vue project, leaving completely unchanged but just adding the Vue Devtools, same error.

Anyone out there who managed to get this working?
Thank you for your help.